# Make list always display one line of elements in a fixed width div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am struggling to make a list always display elements on 1 line only.

To understand this better let me first show some code:

html structure is this:

```
<div id="tab-content">
 <div id="part-list">
    <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS style is this:

```
#tab-content{
                    overflow: auto;
                    height: 100%;
                    position:relative;
                    background-color: #373837;
                    color: white;
                    padding-left:20px;
                    padding-right:20px;
          }

#tab-content ul{
                    display: block;
                    list-style: none outside none;
                   overflow: auto;
                   white-space: nowrap;

          }
          #tab-content ul li{
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 7px;
                    margin-right: 4px;
                    font-style: italic;
                    color: #cccccc;
          }
```

I need the ul to have its items on 1 line no matter if it gets bigger than the containing div. If it does get bigger than the scrolling bar should appear. Right now it just gets wrapped..

I am using jscrollPane on #part-list because i have a custom scrollbar there.

PS: specifying a bigger width than the containing div, say 150%, is not a solution as the list has its content pulled out from a db and its length is dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `float:left` to `display:inline`. Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LgKsY/

```
#tab-content ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

However in changing it from *block* to *inline* your padding/height will seem different. They key here is set a height on the `ul` of say 30px and then a line-height of the same value i.e. 30px on the `li`. I have also removed `overflow:auto` from the `ul` in this version as it is redundant because the `div` already does that job. 2nd example: http://jsfiddle.net/LgKsY/1/

Comment: thanks very much for this, you saved me from a lot of coffee and cigarettes!

Answer (score 2):

Use css `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:block` and with `display:inline-block` use `*float:left !important; /* For IE 7*/` and `_float:left !important; /* For IE 6*/`. Because `disaply:inline-block;` doesn't support IE 6 & 7.

Another solution, you can use `float:left` for all browsers instead off using `display:inline-block`

Comment: i have already marked the previous answer as accepted but yours is works as well, and is a complete solution. I hope whoever reads this post will read all the way because your solution is really what i am looking for.